# How to append and count the number of elements using jq

Tags: json, count, jq

So I have this json. I need to count the number of elements inside the `vulnerabilities[]` arrays

```
{
  "dependencyId": 129707,
  "isVirtual": "false",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
     "name": "vul",
     "severity": "LOW",
    }
   ]
}
{
  "dependencyId": 129708,
  "isVirtual": "false",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
     "name": "vul",
     "severity": "LOW",
    },
    {
     "name": "vul",
     "severity": "HIGH",
    }
  ]
}
{
  "dependencyId": 129709,
  "isVirtual": "false",
  "vulnerabilities": []
}
```

What I have tried is this

```
jq '.' c.json | jq  '{id: .dependencyId, vulnCount: .vulnerabilities[] | length}'
```

**Result :**

```
{
  "id": 129707,
  "vulnCount": 2
}
{
  "id": 129708,
  "vulnCount": 2
}
{
  "id": 129709,
  "vulnCount": 2
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  "id": 129707,
  "vulnCount": 1
}
{
  "id": 129708,
  "vulnCount": 2
}
{
  "id": 129709,
  "vulnCount": 0
}
```

So how do I get the number of vulnerabilities from `vulnerabilities[]` depending the number of element from the array?

Comment: Actually your result shown is wrong, it must show `129708` with count 2 twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need separate invocations of `jq`. You can do it one shot as below invoking the function on the array

```
{ id: .dependencyId, vulnCount: (.vulnerabilities|length) }
```

The issue with your attempt was `[]` exposes all the objects inside the array and the `length` function on the object counts the number of key/value pairs in a given object.

The object in `129707` has two key/value pairs, with key names `name` and `severity`. In second id with `129708`, there are two objects inside, each object is printed with count 2 along with the id. Since `129709` does not have any objects inside, it is totally ignored in the resulting output.